# Is there any good way to reuse a git branch when it has previously been squash merged?

Tags: git

So if I do this:

1. Create a branch "fred" from "development" locally
2. Make a few commits
3. Push changes
4. Squash merge "fred" into "development" on origin
5. Delete "fred" on origin

Then if I try to reuse the "fred" branch for future related changes, I run into the issue of when I try to merge those changes, the original commits show up as needing to be integrated all over again, because of the squash merge - they don't actually exist on origin, only the squashed commit exists.

Is there any way to work around this? I would like to be able to reuse my local branch, but I'm not sure how to do this without either doing a history-preserving merge or getting stuck with all these duplicate commits...

Answer (score 4):

When you are ready to start using your `fred` branch again, you can reset it to whatever commit should be it's new starting point.

So, let's say that you've recently pushed all of `fred`'s content onto the remote `development` branch. `fred` no longer has any unique changes that need to be saved since all of it's (squashed) content is on `development`. Now you are ready to start more work on `fred`.

First switch to `fred`: `git checkout fred`

Then, reset it to your new starting point: `git reset --hard origin/development`

Now you can proceed to work on `fred` as if it was a new branch.

Comment: Oh, that's neat! So all the changes that I previously made to `fred` - they are hidden away somewhere in history but inaccessible, then?

Comment: They would become unreachable from your `fred` branch pointer, but still accessible using `git reflog` if you needed them (until Git auto-garbage-collects which is 30 days by default I believe)

Comment: Note that except for retaining reflog history (which is a big exception!), this is the same as deleting the branch name `fred`, then creating a new and different branch name *also* spelled `fred`.

Comment: OK, I tried this on one of my branches and now I have 14 incoming commits and 7 outgoing commits?! Did I do it wrong?